# Do something when scrolled using buttons / mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using an UP button(`upArrow`) and a DOWN button (`downArrow`) to scroll a div. The code works fine. Below is the code set for those 2 buttons.

My question is, how do I join this when someone uses the mouse wheel to scroll?

Example: If someone uses the `downArrow` button to scroll down and reach at the bottom a pop-up shows  ( `if( val == (items) ){ //reasched end - now do something... }` ). Now how do I make the popup show if someone uses the mouse wheel and instead of the buttons?

```
var numVal = 0,
    val = 0,
    items = 12,
    scrollVal = 300;
$('#downArrow').click(function() {
    numVal = numVal+scrollVal;
    val++;
    $("#itHolder").animate({
        scrollTop: numVal
    });
    if( val == (items) ){
         //reasched end - now do something...
     }
});
$('#upArrow').click(function() {
    numVal = numVal-scrollVal;
    val--;
    $("#itHolder").animate({
        scrollTop: numVal
    });
    if( val == 0 ){
        //reasched top - now do something...
    }
});
```

Comment: try mouseUp instead of click and .on function

Comment: @daremachine thanks. what's the difference?

Comment: You can check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event

Answer (score 0):

You could combine listening for the scrolling event on your containing div, with its scrollTop property to find when you hit the bottom...

```
$(myContainingDiv).on('scroll', function () {
    if (this.scrollTop() == this.height()) {
        // Do Something...
    };
});
```