# Javascript - touch screen unidirectional scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, gesture

I am developing a web application for smartphones. 
Users can horizontally or vertically scrolling at their convenience, but they should not be able to do both at the same time.

I am looking for tips and/or library in javascript and/or css to render scrolling unidirectional.

If the gesture is globally vertical, scrolling is only vertical. If the gesture is globally horizontal, scrolling is horizontal only.

Thank you !

Comment: you'd need to add/remove `overflow-x`/`overflow-y` based on the direction of the initial scroll

Comment: Sounds good, but how to determine the direction of the initial scroll?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event