# Not Working - Header Slide up on scroll down page, and down again on scroll up - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery where I am attempting to hide the header on scroll down and appear on scroll up, but I cannot get it to work? All content that will be slideUp etc... is in a header tag

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
        $(window).scroll(function() {

            var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (currentScrollTop > 80){
                $('header').slideUp(200);}
            else {
                $('header').slideDown(200);}    
        });
    });
```

I can get the header to disappear with the following code but really struggling to make it functional

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('body').scroll(function() {           
            $('header').slideUp(200);
        });
    });
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)

Comment: Thanks but its not the direction I am concerned with, I am looking for an if statement to activate slideup when .scrolltop() is more than 80px and then slidedown when the user scrolls up page again slidedown,

Answer (score 0):

I don't get really what is the effect you want to achieve but what you are probably having wrong is the use of `window` as a referential for `.scroll()` instead of the use of `document`.

So try instead to use `$(document).scroll(function(){...});` as I've tried in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLukue7c/1/).