# Jquery mobile scroll event get direction(up,down) with e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

how i can get the direction from scroll event (mobile) ? (With e.preventDefault() )?

I already tried some scroll events and looked at the event content (via console.log(e))

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)

Comment: No because i use e.preventDefault() so the data is always the same and i cant check the old and the new position.

Comment: can no one help me ? :(