# How to detect whether scrolling up or down in mCustomScrolling

Tags: javascript

How can I detect whether the web page is scrolling downwards or upwards while using Custom Scrollbar?

As I want to hide a particular div while scrolling downwards and show it while scrolling upwards. I am using [**this plugin**](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin).

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please consider the following Help topic [**`How do I ask a good question?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)