# Jquery counter on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, counter

I am trying to make number counter which will work on scroll. When you scroll down, then counter is going from 0 to some number, and when you scroll up, from some number to zero. Numbers are changing during the scroll (if there is no scroll, number stay where it is in that time). Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and check your console

HTML

```
<div class="body">


</div>
```

jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

css

```
.body{
    height:900px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326907/837868) to determin if the scroll goes up or down:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var counter = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
     counter++;
   } else {
     counter--;
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```