# Typing effect when scrolling page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, vertical-scrolling, typing

How do I make the typing effect when the page is scrolling down? I use this code for the start of typing:

```
var typed = new Typed(".class", {
  strings: ["My text."],
  typeSpeed: 40,
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the container having typing text should be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you need to detect scroll down event just to start the typing. You can include [shabdawali](https://github.com/amitguptagwl/shabdawali) js library in your code and [detect for scroll down event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4326845/453767) to play pause typing effect.

```
var typeWriter = shabdawali(el, {
    lines : ["sentence 1", "sentence 2"],
});

var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
       typeWriter.start();
   } else {
      // upscroll code
      typeWriter.pause();
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this plugin.