# How to scroll to a section on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

To explain, if I scroll down once, the page shouldn't move based on the amount I scrolled but it should smooth scroll to the next id directly. If I scroll down once, it should scroll to the id below and if I scroll up, I want to scroll to the id above and not anywhere in between.

For reference, in the pen below, if I am on top section of this pen and I scroll down once, it shouldn't scroll a bit but instead scroll such that middle is in the view.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.top').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("div.middle").offset().top
      }, 1000)
    }),
    $('div.middle').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("div.bottom").offset().top
      }, 1000)
    }),
    $('div.bottom').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("div.top").offset().top
      }, 1000)
    })
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.top {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.middle {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <h1>Top</h1>
</div>
<div class="middle">
  <h1>Middle</h1>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h1>Bottom</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You should think about using a js library that already to that like this one : https://alvarotrigo.com/. But as it does not answer the question i'm gonna answer you soon.

Comment: Just post this as an answer. It works. Found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to [Seann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9554266/seann)'s answer, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10545584/9420243), is to use a handler on the mousewheel event, so that you don't have to keep track of the previous scroll position:

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
        console.log('Scroll up');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Scroll down');
    }
});
```

There are some drawbacks of this method (most notably that it only works if your users are using a mouse), but depending on your specific needs it might work for you.

Also, as [Alex Vand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8978229/alex-vand) mentioned in the comments, [fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/#fullpage) is an excellent library to achieve what you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

I took this from a website I have created with an animated scroll which scrolls a whole page at a time. I did update it to work for your specific request.

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$(document).scroll(function(){
  if((window).scrollTop() > scroll){
    //Scroll Down
    if(window.scrollTop() == $('.top').position().top)
      $("HTML, BODY").animate({ scrollTop: $('.middle').position().top }, 500);
    else $("HTML, BODY").animate({ scrollTop: $('.bottom').position().top }, 500);
  } else {
    //Scroll Up
    if(window.scrollTop() == $('.bottom').position().top)
      $("HTML, BODY").animate({ scrollTop: $('.middle').position().top }, 500);
    else $("HTML, BODY").animate({ scrollTop: $('.top').position().top }, 500);
  }
});
```

Hope it works for you.