# Mouse-wheel & K/board Up/Down bullet navigation based on data-attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a WordPress page that have a slider with pagination and a footer div.

Now, the pagination only contain class `pagination` & `active`, and each pagination options have unique `data-page value`.

May I know **how can I make the mouse-wheel, kboard up/down & page-up/down button to navigate through the pagination** without any external plugin. Also, when the pagination finish, **if the user press down one more time, it will reveal the footer and no active class for the pagination**.

Example like this https://causeeffect.asia/services/

Anyway, I can't replicate 100% because the slider is from WordPress plugin, but the codes below are basically what it looks like.

```js
window.slide = new SlideNav();
```

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.section {
 min-height: 800px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: sans-serif, arial;
 margin: 0;
}

h1, p {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif, arial;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.text-wr {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#section1 {
 background: #5c53aa;
 color: #8d86c3;
}

#section2 {
 background: #4bbfc3;
 color: #81d2d5;
}

#section3 {
 background: #283044;
 color: #686e7c;
}

#section4 {
 background: #ebf5ee;
 color: #aeb9b9;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.title-top {
 font-size: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.title-bottom {
 font-size: 30px;
}

.title-tx {
 font-size: 20px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.nav {
 position: fixed; /*left: 50%;*/
 width: 100%;
 top: 20px;
 z-index: 9;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav a {
 padding: 7px 20px;
 border-radius: 7px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-family: sans-serif, arial;
 font-weight: 100;
}

.nav a.active {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 color: white;
}

.nav a:hover {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://qmixi.github.io/slide-nav/dist/slideNav.js"></script>

    <div class="nav">
        <nav>
            <a href="#section1" class="pagination active" data-page="0">Link to section 1</a>
            <a href="#section2" class="pagination" data-page="1">Link to section 2</a>
            <a href="#section3" class="pagination" data-page="2">Link to section 3</a>
            <a href="#section4" class="pagination" data-page="3">Link to section 4</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="section1" class="section">
        <div class="text-wr">
            <h1 class="title">
                <div class="title-top">Slide Nav Example</div>
                <div class="title-tx">Created by Piotr Kumorek</div>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" class="section">
        <div class="text-wr">
            <h1 class="title">Section 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="section">
        <div class="text-wr">
            <h1 class="title">Section 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section4" class="section">
        <div class="text-wr">
            <h1 class="title">Section 4</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer id="footer" class="section">
        <div class="text-wr">
            <h1 class="title">Footer Area</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery keydown event for up/down/pageup/pagedown event and also can use mouse scroll as well. Check below code for keyboard keys like:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 33 ) { 
        //do your code here for slide next
    } else if(e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 34) { 
       //do your code for slide pervious
    }
}
```

And for mouse scroll, you can use below code referenced from: [How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
   } else {
      // upscroll code
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Hope it helps you.