# How to actively check if a value is incrementing? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a value that emits an incrementing decimal value on scroll from 0 to 1.

Currently the script triggers the change of image on scroll as a scroll will cause the value to increment and the image will only change back once the value returns to 0.

I need a check that actively checks if the value is increasing and if the value stops increasing it should return to the idle image.

'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Character = document.getElementById("character");

(function($) {
    $.jInvertScroll(['.scroll'],        
        {
        height: 6000,                   
        onScroll: function(percent) {   
            console.log(percent);
            if (percent++) {
                Character.style.backgroundImage = "url(/examples/images/gif/sqeekiWalk.gif)";
            } else {
                Character.style.backgroundImage = "url(/examples/images/gif/sqeekiIdle.gif)"
            }
        }
    });
}(jQuery));

</script>
```

'

Comment: Could you try `if (percent > 0)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)

Comment: Side note, `if (percent++)` may not be doing what you expect, `++` after a number will increment it, but **will not** return the new value. You'd need `if (++percent)` if you're trying to check the incremented number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)