# How to detect user scrooll down, top and stop both 3 event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Can anyone help me to detech 3 event in jquery.

I want when user scroll down it show log down scroll
when user scroll top it show log top scroll
when user stop scrolling top it show log stop scroll

I want when user scroll down it show log down scroll
when user scroll top it show log top scroll
when user stop scrolling top it show log stop scroll

Comment: check this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event

Comment: @Maulik I am able to detect up scroom and down scroll but I am stuck in when user stop scrolling. Basically I add diffent css on both 3 event when user scroll top I want add css 1 when user scroll down I want add css 2 when user stop scrolling I want add css 3

Comment: check this also

https://codepen.io/ant1mas/pen/KMVZrb

and this

http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/jquerymobile/event_scrollstop.asp.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 0):

check this example for all 3 events

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("scrollstop",function(){
    console.log('stop');
    console.log('your css 3 here');
  }); 
$(document).on('mousewheel', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
        console.log('Scroll up');
        console.log('your css 1 here');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Scroll down');
        console.log('your css 2 here');
    }
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```