# How do I use JQuery to detect if a user scrolls to the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, scroll

And once it hits the bottom,then have a callback function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962558/javascript-detect-scroll-end

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962558/javascript-detect-scroll-end

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user has scrolled to the bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use .scroll() event in this way on your window:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```

check [live demo](http://jsbin.com/igiqov/)

to detect if the user is 3/4 down the page you can try this one

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - .75*$(document).height()) {
       alert("3/4th of bottom!");
   }
});
```

Comment: generally it works, but with "alert" it crashed my FF, it literally "blacked out". But I tested with console.log and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks. THis works! What if I want to detect if the user is 3/4 down the page?

Comment: I think your solution for 3/4 down the page is actually looking for "75 pixels from the bottom of the page".  Changing `$(document).height() - 75` to `$(document).height() * 0.75` should do the trick.

Comment: that live demo doesnt work for me... Chrome 44.0.2403.125 if it helps)

Comment: This works wonderfully for me everywhere but on my mobile. If I can figure out the issue, I'll post an update.

Comment: Addendum: nothing wrong on phone: I was testing a lazy-loading scroll function and didn't have enough data to trigger it on the server I was testing the mobile on. Works great!