# Twitter-Bootstrap catching when navbar-fixed-top is scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

does anyone knows if is possible via css or js to catch when twitter-bootstrap navbar-fixed-top is scrolling?

I guess i should check when user scroll the page, but if is possible i would like to get it more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   alert("bottom!");
}
});
```

Tis is actually found here: [How do I use JQuery to detect if a user scrolls to the bottom of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697748/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-detect-if-a-user-scrolls-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

You can change where it detects to, so you pick where.