# How to detect that the end of a scrollable element has been reached?

Tags: javascript

I am displaying 10 wordpress post titles in a list followed by a "Load more" button that loads the next 10 results.

How would I automatically trigger that button (let's make it a javascript event) when reaching the end of the scrollable parent of that list?

Is it possible to detect the position of the scrollbar, or the visibility of the last list item on the screen? what is the most failprove method?

Thanks you for your tips and tricks guys!

P.S. I do not work with jQuery so no need to suggest solutions that are using it :).

Answer (score 0):

You can check how far down a page/element is scrolled by listening on the `scroll` event listener `myElm.addEventListener('scroll',scrolled,false);` with a function like that defined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4638434/1615483 (which does not actually rely on jQuery)