# HTML overflow javascript

Tags: javascript, html, triggers

I have a div which is scrollable using the `overflow-y` set to auto. What I want to do is that beneath this `div` I like to have a simple button which is `disabled` and I like it to be `enabled` after I reached the bottom of the `div`.
 Can this be achieved?

Comment: "A picture says more than thousand words." Can you post a link to jsfiddle example or post your source code?

Comment: are you trying to say you want to have a **Back to top-button**? or **Top of page-button** ?

Comment: @Paw Cabelin, sounds more like "I have read and I accept the rules"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with jquery:

```
$("#idDiv").scroll( function() {
  if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() == $(this).outerHeight())
    // what you want to do ...
    $('#idButton').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
```

see this : [javascript: detect scroll end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962558/javascript-detect-scroll-end)