# Detect scrolled-to-document-end implementation in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll

I know how to detect the document end while scrolling in plain JS, my problem is - how to implement that in AngularJS, I know I should attach the scroll event to both the [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) and [$document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document), my question is about where to implement the behavior?, directives?, services?, if anyone can show me what is the right way to implement that [kind of detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962558/javascript-detect-scroll-end) in AngularJS I'll be very thankful.

Comment: You should go check out the source for this module. http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/. It does a lot with scroll detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're doing it can go in a combination of places. Typically when dealing with DOM manipulation (which is what I assume will be happening) you should use a directive - something like:

```
app.directive("scrollDetector", ["$document", "$window", function($document, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                //scroll logic here
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

And then implement the `scroll-detector` directive. (ex: `<div scroll-detector></div>`)

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with it for a long time- stumbled across the library: http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html.

Based on your use-case, you could do something like:

```
<div infinite-scroll="addMoreItems()">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">Item number {{$index}}: {{$item}}</div>
</div>
```

As it allows you to attach this to any div- you could almost do anything in the function you want to.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look.

Comment: Updated link: http://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html