# Jquery Scroll to BOTTOM to load new content is working in opposite way (i.e) on Scrolling TOP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a website, which has scroll to **BOTTOM** to load AJAX content.

I use this Jquery Scroll function:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 

  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  
    {

      alert("ScrollTop + Window Height = "+$(window).scrollTop()+ " + " +
      $(window).height()+ " == Document Height = "+$(document).height());

      // This get's alerted only when i reach TOP
    }

  });
```

But this works only if i reach **TOP**

Do anyone had this problem before ?

Comment: Refer below answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962558/javascript-detect-scroll-end

Comment: @VinayakShedgeri, what is wrong in this Jquery scroll? Its working good in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uhL1zbso/ when i tried there

Comment: first read this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript

Comment: @VinayakShedgeri, by the way my code is right, but my question is why its working in opposite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue,

Its My Mistake that, i didn't include doc type in my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And that's why the scroll worked in reverse order. After including the doctype at the 1st line of the code, it's working good as expected (i.e) Scrolling to the bottom of page to load more AJAX content or call function().

So when ever you write a code start with **< !DOCTYPE html >**

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code for your issue.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() -$(window).height())     
    {
       load_data(); 
    }
});
```

And for more information visit this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035180/jquery-load-more-data-on-scroll)

Comment: One more suggestion is that please do the proper format of your html. There are Start with <html> and end with </html> tag . no any code outside those tag. also add body tag.

Comment: Yep added body tag.

Comment: hi Divyesh, i have missed the <!DOCTYPE html> in my code, that's why the Content got loaded on reaching TOP i.e in reverse order.

Comment: Have u ever faced this like issue? Just a Doctype made this issue.

Comment: I have seen your source which is improper so i have commented " There are Start with <html> and end with </html> tag . no any code outside those tag. also add body tag"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand defference between window and document
for example 800wX600h
($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()

0+600=600

So 
it should be 0+600 > 600

replace it with 
($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()

Comment: So what should i need to change in the above code ?

Comment: change your equal to greater then or try to display the value of scrollTop() and  $(window).height()  and debug yourself

Comment: I have added the alert `alert("ScrollTop + Window Height = "+$(window).scrollTop()+ " + " + $(window).height()+ " == Document Height = "+$(document).height());`  Please take a look now.

Comment: hi Vinayak, i have missed the <!DOCTYPE html> in my code, that's why the Content loads on reaching TOP.